# Show a linear combination of linear transformations is still a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been posed the following question:
[image]

I am unsure where to begin showing that $2F - G$ is still a linear transformation. Should I show that $2F-G$ conforms to the 3 properties of linear transformations? 
Any suggestions/hints would be appreciated

Comment: Yeah. Just verify that $2F-G$ still satisfies the properties of linear transformations, using the fact that $F$ and $G$ individually satisfy the properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically answered your own question; if you want to show that something is a linear transformation, just use the definition!

What will save the day (of course) is the hypothesis that both $F$ and $G$ are already linear transformations. You said three properties, but technically speaking you only need two, as respecting scalar multiplication will give you that $0$ is mapped to $0$.

So now just write it all out:
$$
H(u+v)=2F(u+v)-G(u+v) = 2F(u)+2F(v)-G(u)-G(v) = \cdots
$$
$$
H(cv)=2F(cv)-G(cv)=2cF(v)-cG(v) = \cdots
$$

Comment: thanks for the reply!